# How can I use word-wrap inside a table?

Tags: html

I have a table, that fits 100% into my window. But when my text is very long, it doesn't break, so my table will be bigger then my window:

```css
td {
  word-wrap:break-all;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</td>
    <td>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The thing about **word** wrap is that it wraps the text between *words*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `td { word-break: break-all;}` instead

```css
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</td>
    <td>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break